# Sequencing a PCR product with no band

Tags: molecular-genetics, dna-sequencing, pcr, gel-electrophoresis

I did a PCR that successfully showed the appropriate bands one time, but when I tried to re-do the same PCR just at a larger quantity to send for Sanger sequencing, very faint or no bands were seen. This same primer set has been used successfully for larger quantities before, it may be possible that the issue is in the gel. I cannot afford to run any more gels with this product, so my question is; how important is a visible band for Sanger sequencing? Will sequencing fail with a faint band?

Comment: How much did you scale up your reaction? How much do you usually scale up (2x, 5x, 10x)? Do you have any other way to measure DNA concentration reliably?

Comment: So for the functioning PCR reaction, the total volume was 10µl; 0.25µl each for forward and reverse primers, 2 µl of 5x premade mastermix (including the dNTPs, Taq polymerase, MgCl2, dye, etc), 5.5µl PCR grade water and 2µl DNA. The upgraded one was 25 µl, 0.5 each for the primers, 5µl of the mastermix, 17µl water and 2µl DNA. Do you think the DNA volume is a problem? It never caused issues before

Comment: As for the DNA concentration, we do have a nanodrop machine but it isn't exactly reliable

Comment: It looks like you're using the same amount of template DNA in your scaled up reaction as your smaller one ( 2µl), which essentially means it's at a lower starting concentration. Assuming the same number of cycles, you would ended up with the same amount of amplified product, just in a larger volume, which could be why the bands are faint in the larger one (though, that level of dilution shouldn't be enough to make a band disappear completely).

Comment: Not really responding to the issue but: agarose responds very well to remelting many times, if all I'm doing is looking for bands and not gel purifying, I used to reuse the same agarose to pour new gels dozens of times until it got really gross. Granted, this may not work so well for precast gels. My opinion: if you haven't evaluated it on a gel I'm not sure that it's a good idea to sequence.

Comment: Thanks, and while the template amount staying the same has not affected it before, I will try to increase it next time. And by not affording to test any more, I had meant I needed to retain a certain amount of the PCR product to send for sequencing, so I had no more left to run gels with. However, the remelting of gels sounds useful, how do you erase the previously added PCR samples from it?

Comment: @Nalonda understood. btw tagging with a "@" is necessary to notify us. Why can't you simply repeat the PCR with more template and use that? Are you out of template? As for remelting, once you remelt the DNA diffuses/degrades over time. Any particular band will still be brighter than background for visualization purposes. However the DNA doesn't get erased so you shouldn't purify from it! and it could contaminate e.g. your gel rig if post-pcr contam is a concern. You might consider having one gel rig for this and then a separate dedicated "clean" one.

Comment: @MaximilianPress Thanks, I just joined Stack Exchange so I didn't know. And also thanks for the gel tips! As for the PCR, I'm trying to keep the number of times I repeat the PCR to a minimum as I want to make sure there is enough of the other components left for a bigger project I have coming up. Anyway I have my answer now, so appreciate it!

Comment: In your original post you asked if the failure to detect the expected amplified product could be due to the gel.  What issue with an agarose gel would reduce the yield of a PCR product?